# Dependent contracts for structs in Racket

Tags: racket, contract

Suppose I define a struct for a set with its "center".

```
(struct centered-set (center elems))
```

I want to guarantee the following conditions.

- `elems` is a set.
- `center` is an member of `elems`.

I can express the conditions with `#:guard`. Is there a way to express the same conditions as a contract?

For functions, `->i` works as a combinator for that kind of dependent contracts. How to express dependent contracts for structs?

Comment: Take a look at [struct/dc](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/data-structure-contracts.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fstruct-dc..rkt%29._struct%2Fdc%29%29)

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase Thank you. As far as I can see, `struct/dc` is for a contract that _accepts struct instances_. I want to impose contracts _on structs_, like `(contract-out [struct ...])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, `contract-out` doesn't support anything like that. However, you can simulate the functionality by providing the constructor and accessors manually with the contract attached:

```
#lang racket

(module foo racket
  (provide (contract-out [bt (-> any/c any/c any/c (bst/c 1 10))]
                         [bt-val (-> (bst/c 1 10) any/c)]
                         [bt-left (-> (bst/c 1 10) any/c)]
                         [bt-right (-> (bst/c 1 10) any/c)]))

  (define (bst/c lo hi)
    (or/c #f
          (struct/dc bt
                     [val (between/c lo hi)]
                     [left (val) #:lazy (bst/c lo val)]
                     [right (val) #:lazy (bst/c val hi)])))

  (struct bt (val left right)))

(require 'foo)

(bt 11 #f #f)
```

It should be possible to write a [provide transformer](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html?q=provide+transformer#%28mod-path._racket%2Fprovide-transform%29) to automate this process.

Comment: What's the purpose of `(or/c #f ...)` in the definition of `bst/c` ?

Comment: A binary tree is defined as either an internal node or a leaf. `#f` represents a leaf in the above program, and `bt` represents an internal node.